# In azure ml pipeline , error while training the model with large dataset

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to train the model with binary logistic regression model,with a dataset of 3000 data points. while creating the pipeline , it fails at the training model step.

Please help me in training the model with large dataset or retrain the model continuously.

Also Do pipelines have any limitation on the dataset? if so, what is the limit

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen there is a limitation for training dataset size. May I know how you do the pipeline? If you are using Azure Machine Learning Designer, could you please try the enterprise version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-ml-pipelines#building-pipelines-with-the-designer

Also, I have attached a tutorial here for large data pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-batch-scoring-classification

Comment: Yes, I am using the enterprise version.While training the model, the error is as follows: "User program failed with ColumnUniqueValuesExceededError: Number of unique values in column: "message" is greater than allowed."